# Meteor - correct structure and scope for javascript functions and files?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

First of all, I am familiar with what the [Meteor docs say about this](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp), which I have summarized here:

- Files in subdirectories are loaded before files in parent
  directories, so that files in the deepest subdirectory are loaded
  first, and files in the root directory are loaded last.
- Within a directory, files are loaded in alphabetical order by
  filename.
- After sorting as described above, all files under directories named
  lib are moved before everything else (preserving their order).
- Finally, all files that match main.* are moved after everything else
  (preserving their order).

(Not sure why they say "moved" instead of "loaded", but I think they just mean "loaded".)

My app has the following structure:

```
├── client/
│   ├── html/
│   │   ├── main.html
│   │   ├── nav.html
│   │   └── login.html
│   ├── js/
│   │   ├── lib/
│   │   │   └── util.js
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   └── nav.js
│   └── my_app.less
├── packages/
│   └── some_stuff_here
├── server/
│   └── main.js
├── shared.js
├── smart.json
└── smart.lock
```

In `client/js/nav.js` file I have the following JavaScript code:

```
Template.nav.nav_close = function() {
    return ! Session.get(slugify(this.name)+'-nav-close')
}
```

In `client/js/lib/util.js` file I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var slugify = function(value) {
    if (value) {
        return value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/\./g, '-').toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the `client/js/lib/util.js` file should get loaded first, which will make my `slugify` function available, and then `client/js/nav.js` should get loaded and the `slugify` function should be available to it.

In fact what happens is that I see the following error in my Chrome console:

```
Exception from Deps recompute function: ReferenceError: slugify is not defined
    at Object.Template.nav.nav_close (http://localhost:3000/client/js/nav.js?4d7c7953063828c0e4ec237c1a5c67b849076cb5:2:26)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slugify` has file scope because it is declared with `var`. Remove `var` to give it package (application) scope.

[Meteor Namespacing](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing)

```
slugify = function(value) {
    if (value) {
        return value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/\./g, '-').toLowerCase();
    }
}
```